# replace substring only one time, one place

Tags: php, replace

Example:

```
string1="ah ah I love you ah ah ah ah";
```

After replacement:

```
string1="ah ah I love you ah thank you ah ah";
```

The above  means 'ah' at fourth position should be replaced by 'thank you'

I don't know how to code task above by PHP. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you always want the 4th "ah"? or a specific word at a location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = "ah ah I love you ah ah ah ah";
echo preg_replace_callback('/ah/', function($m) {
    static $count = 0;
    if(++$count == 4) return 'thank you';
    else return $m[0];
}, $string);
```

How it works: Each time `ah` matches the callback function is invoked. The static `$count` variable is increased and when it's the fourth match it returns the replacement string, otherwise the originally matched string.

Answer (score 1):

A non regex approach.

```
$string = "ah ah I love you ah ah ah ah";

// search for the 4th 'ah'
$pos = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $pos = strpos($string, 'ah', $pos);
    $pos++;
}
// substring before the found, the replacement, and after the found
$result = substr($string, 0, $pos-1).'thank you'.substr($string, $pos+1);
```